# Twitter bootstrap: Why .row or .row-fluid does not have height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Twitter bootstrap framework, but been in web dev for a year. Just wondering why the .row or .row-fluid does not have height at all?

I've been using padding: for the container to make the height so my background image is visible. And I've found I have to do this all the time!!! What is the purposed way to solve this issue? Most of my div elements have no content but different background image. Thanks.

Comment: If you came here like I did trying to figure out why rows *with* content have 0 height, then you should read this question and answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20971813/352087

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.row` and `.row-fluid` were meant to be the building blocks of the twitter's bootstrap grid system and are not meant for presentation, much rather containment, as the name implies, how else would rows of blocks be presented?. Though you can easily add height to the rows if your application calls for it by creating a new class with the height you want and add it to the rows div. Or better yet, add height your divs with a background-image attached.