# twitter-bootstrap row-fluid doesn't adjust height according to it's child size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/rEsG2/) fiddle. It's essentially a

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am just wondering why the `row-fluid` doesn't adjust the height based on the `sidebar` height? I can see the sidebar has a height of 1450px, so if all container div's by default adjust's to it's child div's size then it should also have a height of 1450px. If I check the height of the row-fluid, it stays at 0. How do I make this adjust accordingly?

Comment: You're using Bootstrap 3.0.3 in the fiddle, but BS 3 no longer has `row-fluid` and `container-fluid`.. it's just `row` and `container` now.

Comment: @Skelly nope it seems they actually kept both of them: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width)".

Comment: In 3.0, there was neither `row-fluid` nor `container-fluid`. In Bootstrap 3.1, `container-fluid` has returned, but there is still no `row-fluid`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add class .clearfix to the row-fluid and it will work :)

Comment: it's a problem with float. You have add the float:left or right in the .sidebar. For that reason you must clear the float and you can do that with .clearfix that has clear:both declaration.